# How to apply changes in grid when data is updated from another windows form?

Tags: winforms, datagrid

I have data grid in form1 which contains product details, then I open one product in another form form2 and update product. If i make any changes in second form by clicking the update button and save it then related changes should be applied in form1 grid.
Please help me how to do that.

Comment: place some code what you have written in form load.

Answer (score 0):

change form2's constructor like this and add a variable for Form1 ;

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 mainform;
    public Form2(Form1 main)
    {
        mainform= main;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //other code..
}
```

and For update button

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     mainform.dataGridWiev1.DoWhatYouWantLikeThisCall();
 }
```